# redux-form formValues selector returns previous state

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I trigger an action creator (https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/actioncreators.md/) for updating a form value from an external component of the form. After this update I want to get the new form values.

The component that triggers the actions is connected to redux-form in this way

```
 connect(
    state => ({
      formValues: getFormValues("refineForm")(state)
    }),
    dispatch => ({
      changeFormValue: input => dispatch(change("refineForm", input, "")),
      unTouchFormValue: input => dispatch(untouch("refineForm", input))
    })
  )
```

when onClick events actions are dispatched and right after selector called to get new values.

```
  props.changeFormValue(input);
  props.unTouchFormValue(input);
  const newFormValues = props.formValues
```

Redux dev tools shows me that actions are triggered, redux state is updated (visually I see how the input is cleared!) however the selector provided by redux-form returns me the previous redux state form values.

what do I overlook?

Comment: Calling redux actions does not mutate the current props of a component. It will trigger a store change that will trigger `mapStateToProps()` to be called that may pass new props to the component that triggers a re-render of that component. Everything that happens in the click handler right after the call of an action does still only see the "old" props.

Comment: Hi @trixn you are right! my bad I guess I needed somebody to remember me how react works :), I will use a lifecycle method to handle new props passed to the component.